# Merge tabs in a tab

Tags: javascript, php, opencart, smarty

we use an opencart module which displays some products from a parent category, splitted by their subcategories (tabs). As we click on every tab we willl see products from the other subcategory. Our need is to see all products in a tap-panel.

I am writing down here the full tpl code which is responsible for this apperance and the url for everyone want to check is the following http://dedegkikas.gr/new/

Any help appreciated..thanks in advance.

```
<div class="tab-content">
                <?php $i = 0; foreach ($tabs as $key=>$tab) { $i++;?>
                <?php

                    $products = $tab['products'];
                    $active = ($i==1)?"active":'';
                ?>
                    <div class="tab-pane <?php echo $active;?> carousel slide" id="tab<?php echo $id."-cat".$key;?>">
                    <?php if( count($products) > $itemsperpage ) { ?>
                    <div class="carousel-controls margin-top--40 top-0">
                        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#tab<?php echo $id."-cat".$key;?>" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#tab<?php echo $id."-cat".$key;?>" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="owl-carousel"  data-show="<?php echo ($columns_count); ?>" data-pagination="false" data-navigation="true">
                        <?php if (empty($products)): ?>
                            <div class="padding-20 style-left"><?php echo $objlang->get("entry_category");?></div>
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <?php $pages = array_chunk( $products, $itemsperpage);?>
                        <?php foreach ($pages as  $k => $tproducts ) {   ?>
                        <div class="item <?php if($k==0) {?>active<?php } ?>">
                            <?php foreach( $tproducts as $i => $product ) {  $i=$i+1;?>
                            <?php if( $i%$cols == 1 || $cols == 1) { ?>
                            <div class="row products-row <?php ;if($i == count($tproducts) - $cols +1) { echo "last";} ?>"><?php //start box-product?>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <div class="col-lg-<?php echo $span;?> col-md-<?php echo $span;?> col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-layout product-grid border">
                                <?php require($layout); ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php if( $i%$cols == 0 || $i==count($tproducts) ) { ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want to do?

1. Removing carousel and show all products in grid view.

Solution: Edit the tpl like you have mentioned above.

2. You want to display all product in that category and its sub categories.

Solution: Go to the module controller and remove the limit and also add another foreach loop for sub categories products.

Comment: If you are uncertain about what the desired result is, then the correct action would be to vote to close the answer as Unclear instead of posting an answer.